# Do not get input when doing Java Compiler

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm doing a simple java compiler. My program is running, but if it is going to scan, it will not receive input and will freeze.

A small code from my compiler

```
public class ProcessBuilderMultipleCommandsExample {
    static String backSlashFl = "C:\\Users\\xxA\\Desktop";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,

            IOException {
        // multiple commands
        // /C Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
        ProcessBuilder pbC = new ProcessBuilder( //COMPİLE
                "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd " + backSlashFl + "&& javac " + "Test" + ".java"); 
        Process processC = pbC.start();


        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( //RUN
                "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd " + backSlashFl + "&& java " + "Test");

        Process process = pb.start();
        IOThreadHandler outputHandler = new IOThreadHandler(
                process.getInputStream());
        outputHandler.start();
        process.waitFor();
        System.out.println(outputHandler.getOutput());
    }

    private static class IOThreadHandler extends Thread {
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        IOThreadHandler(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public void run() {
            Scanner br = null;
            try {
                br = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = null;
                while (br.hasNextLine()) {
                    line = br.nextLine();
                    output.append(line
                            + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
            } finally {
                br.close();
            }
        }

        public StringBuilder getOutput() {
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's working in the back, but how do I get the input part?

Here's the file I want to compile and run.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numberScan {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
    int a=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number= " + a);
}
}
```

I'm waiting for your help.

---

Editted

Now when I run the GUI, the Run key is pressed. What do you think I should do?

```
buttonRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        String backSlashFl = file.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "\\\\");
        backSlashFl = backSlashFl.replace(flName + ".java", "");

        try {

            execute("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd " + backSlashFl + " && java  " + flName);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dosya çalıştı!","Bilgilendirme", 
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ae) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ae.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e2){
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

});
```

When the GUI app runs, this run button remains.

Comment: The 'edit' is actually a different question. You **could** ask this as a new question, but this would be a duplicate: This has already been asked **many** times before. Long story short: You have to run the code that is contained in your `actionPerformed` method in a new thread. Roughly: Replace the contents of this method with `new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { /* the code that is currently in your method */ }).start();` - for details, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241727/java-jbutton-actionperformed-freezing and **many** other questions. I'd suggest to undo the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the given code. I tried to squeeze it into a comment, but now decided to extend it to an answer:

- The class that you want to compile is called `numberScan`, but obviously stored in a file called `Test.java`. A public class can only be stored in a file that has the same name as the class. Call the class `NumberScan`, and call the file `NumberScan.java`.
- You are only trying to print the output that is provided by the input stream. But you are **not** printing the result that is provided by the **error** stream (so if there are errors, you will not see them!). Also, you only printed the output of the `Process process` (which is used for running the program). You did not print the output of the `Process processC`, which was used for compiling the program.
- The reason of why you don't see any output is that the line

  ```
  System.out.println(outputHandler.getOutput());
  ```

  is executed **before** the process is finished. You used `waitFor`, but the `output` is filled by a different thread - namely, the `IOThreadHandler`. The `getOutput` method could only be called *after* the `IOThreadHandler` has finished, but if you want to continuously update the output, then this will not work.

It is not entirely clear what you want to achieve, but guessing from the code that you provided, your goal seems to be to create a program that

- Compiles the given Java file
- Executes the resulting Java program
- Prints possible error messages and the output that is created by the program
- Important: Allows *interacting* with the program, in the sense that it should be possible to send input to the `System.in` of the program.

The last two points are particularly hard to achive manually. You would have to set up threads for reading the input stream and the error stream. These would require some trickery to make sure that the data is read *continuously* while the program is executed. Additionally, you would have to set up a thread that forwards the data that the user enters to the Java program that is executed in its own process.

Fortunately, all this has become fairly trivial with Java 7: You can simply set an appropriate [`ProcessBuilder.Redirect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html) for all the streams (namely, the redirect `INHERIT`), so that all the streams are mapped to the corresponding streams of the surrounding program.

Here is an example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ProcessBuilderMultipleCommandsExample {
    private static String path = "C:\\Users\\xxA\\Desktop";

    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        execute("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd " + path + " && javac " + "NumberScan" + ".java"); 
        execute("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd " + path + " && java  " + "NumberScan");
    }

    private static void execute(String ... commands) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Executing "+Arrays.asList(commands));

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        processBuilder.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        processBuilder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);

        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now when I run the GUI, the Run key is pressed. I added my question. Can you help me?